# Open file in default editor from bash

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, terminal

How do I open a file my script generated with the default GUI editor with bash?

On OS X there is the command `open`, but as far as I know that doesn't exist on linux. What is a good cross-platform alternative?

(executing `open somefile.ext` on OS X does the same as if I double clicked the file in Finder).

Comment: Is `xdg-open file.ext` an option?

Answer (score 16):

Mostly close to this is [`xdg-open`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open):

```
$ xdg-open somefile.ext
```

Comment: How to change and view associations: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62585/how-do-i-set-a-new-xdg-open-setting

Answer (score 5):

On linux you have `kde-open` and `gnome-open` for specific desktop environments, and `xdg-open` is more generic but must still be run from a DE.

On windows, (obviously not `bash` but `cmd.exe`), I believe the similar command is `start`.

With bash a cross-platform code could be:

```
if which xdg-open &> /dev/null; then
    xdg-open $file       # linux
else
    open $file           # mac
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

On your .profile

> export EDITOR='~/bin/mate -w'

and your bash use this editor

Comment: This implies you have to edit `.profile` of each user, and somehow keep it synchronized with the default application defined in the desktop file-association database.

Comment: You can use at Bash at any time. Is for that session.

Comment: If you're writing this for yourself, sure - you could even hardcode your editor in the script. If it's for other users, I don't see how you can assert that `mate` is what they want. On my system your path isn't even valid.

Comment: what does the "-w" indicate? It does have the effect I'm looking for (aka, it writes the file) but it forces a bunch of new windows to open up when using Atom which is highly distracting.

Comment: In that case editor was TextMate: -w, --wait             Wait for file to be closed by TextMate.