# C++ (Unix): Open a text file with the default editor

Tags: c, linux, unix, default, text-editor

The question is above and my Google search wasn't succesfull. I guess I need to get the default editor and then use `system("editor file.txt");`? How could I get the default editor?

Edit: I don't know why but stackoverflow doesn't like my "Hey,"... then not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open file in default editor from bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627767/open-file-in-default-editor-from-bash).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Sorry but I can't aggree. That's not C++ and someone could give me an alternative to system().

Comment: Fair enough. I was only trying to point you to `xdg-open`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Ok thanks. Are there any disadvantages by using xdg-open instead of bin/sensible-editor(pts's answer)?

Comment: `xdg-open` is a freedesktop.org tool, `sensible-editor` is a Debian tool... I guess it depends on the platforms you want to support.

Comment: Indeed - the complexity of the solution is increased depending on which OSs you intend to support. You should also be aware that using a general purpose editor *could* introduce a big security hole.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no official solution. Here is my recommendation for opening up a text editor:

If the filename extension is `.txt`, and `xdg-open` is avaliable on `$PATH` and the `$DISPLAY` variable is nonempty, then use `xdg-open`. Otherwise use `/usr/bin/sensible-editor` if it exists. Otherwise, use `getenv("EDITOR")`, `getenv("VISUAL")` or `getenv("SELECTED_EDITOR")`. If none of them are set, try `nano`, `nano-tiny` and then `vi`.

Comment: Worth adding: `xdg-open` is not "official part of C++", but it is part of the "most widely?" followed Linux desktop standard: https://freedesktop.org/wiki/

Answer (score 4):

There is an example to get default editor environment, from visudo (It use default editor to open sudoers file ) source

```
/*
     * Check EDITOR and VISUAL environment variables to see which editor
     * the user wants to use (we may not end up using it though).
     * If the path is not fully-qualified, make it so and check that
     * the specified executable actually exists.
     */
    if ((UserEditor = getenv("EDITOR")) == NULL || *UserEditor == '\0')
    UserEditor = getenv("VISUAL");
    if (UserEditor && *UserEditor == '\0')
    UserEditor = NULL;
    else if (UserEditor) {
    if (find_path(UserEditor, &Editor, getenv("PATH")) == FOUND) {
        UserEditor = Editor;
    } else {
        if (def_flag(I_ENV_EDITOR)) {
        /* If we are honoring $EDITOR this is a fatal error. */
        (void) fprintf(stderr,
            "%s: specified editor (%s) doesn't exist!\n",
            Argv[0], UserEditor);
        Exit(-1);
        } else {
        /* Otherwise, just ignore $EDITOR. */
        UserEditor = NULL;
        }
    }
    }
```

You can check http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/sudo/sudo-9/sudo/visudo.c for the complete code.